# How to interprete the effects on multiple `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` on TestObserver#triggerActions?

Tags: testing, rx-java2

I have spent certain efforts on multiple rounds and occasion in truly understanding  `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`. After I examined the blog [when-multiple-subscribeons-do-have-effect](https://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2017/11/when-multiple-subscribeons-do-have.html) word by word with corresponding code snippet executed on my local laptop, I am relatively comfortable to say that now I get it.

However, what I still do not understand and I wish to obtain a deeper understanding is the relationship of `TestScheduler#triggerActions` and `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`.

I have created a dedicated pull request example [here](https://github.com/TonyTangAndroid/HelloRxJava/pull/20/files) to demonstrate my confusion. It would be greatly appreciate that some expert in the community could provide insight to explain why or provide any example  on how to write **deterministic test code** to assert `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`.

Comment: Tasks created by `subscribeOn` travel upstream, while items travel downstream thus `observeOn` tasks that deliver those item(s) happen downward. Hence the only test that works unless you keep triggerActioning.